# deleting old Coredata classes and adding new ones causing crashes in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have recently shifted from Xcode 3.2 to 4.2. I have deleted some entities in my Coredata model and also the classes associated with it which were created in 3.2 version.I have added the same entities ones again and created new NSManagedObject classes for those entities. Now my app is getting crashed with out any error messages. But i am pretty sure that it is getting crashed while trying to create the Coredata objects. Even my project.sqlite is also not getting created .I wish i could post some code snippets here... But, i dont exactly know the problem area... Can anyone help me with this....

After some debugging i found that the app is getting crashed at the following line

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still in the development phase, clean your project, remove your application from the iPhone (or the simulator, using the same *touch and hold* gesture), and run it again. This will have removed your database from the application data.

If you already have published your application and want to allow your users to keep their data, you will need to look at how to do a [migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response Guillaume. i am still in development phase and  using the simulator for development. Please refer my updated question to see some code snippets and help me in that context please....

Comment: Same thing apply for simulator: remove the application like you would on the device, by touch-holding it, then using the cross.

Comment: Seeing where it crashes, I still think the steps I have listed can help. If not, at least it is the first step of troubleshooting.

Comment: i have cleaned the build, deleted the simulator build, cleaned the project files but still no luck dude..:(

Comment: Then you need to post your crash trace.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply.... like i mentioned in my question, the app is getting crashed without any error or exception report in the GDB...

Comment: What happens when you type: "bt" (without the quotes) in Xcode console after the crash?